# Is there any package like pm2 for django apps

Tags: django, pm2

Question:

I have a Django app running on a server, and I want to use PM2 to manage the process. However, when I try to start the app with PM2, it gives me an error. Here is my command:

```
pm2 start myapp
```

And here is the error message:

```
Error: script not found or unable to stat: myapp
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I use PM2 to manage my Django app?

Answer (score 0):

You can define a pm2 script e.g

pm2{name}.json

with the following contents:

```
 {
  "apps": [
    {
      "name": "{name}",
      "cwd": "/srv/{name}",
      "args": "runserver",
      "script": "manage.py",
      "exec_mode": "fork",
      "exec_interpreter": "python"
    }
  ]
}
```

and run it with pm2 start {name}

obviously you need to replace {name} with your project's name.